# Azure Release Pipeline Powershell Task Fails

Tags: powershell, ssis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I have an Azure Release Pipeline with an Azure Powershell Task inline script that fails.  I am running a self hosted build agent.  The Powershell command works fine when I execute it locally from Windows Powershell. The task is attempting to start a DataFactory SSIS Integration Runtime:

```
Start-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup"
                                             -DataFactoryName "my-data-factory"
                                             -Name "myIntegrationRuntime1"
                                             -Force
```

Firstly I get a warning:

> WARNING: AzureRM.Profile already loaded. Az and AzureRM modules cannot
>   be imported in the same session or used in the same script or runbook.
>   If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can
>   use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from
>   your machine. If you are running in Azure Automation, take care that
>   none of your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM modules. More
>   information can be found here: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide.

And then the error:

> The 'Start-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime' command was found in the
>   module 'Az.DataFactory', but the module could not be loaded. For more
>   information, run 'Import-Module Az.DataFactory'.

When I look at the installed modules, I see both AzureRM and Az are installed, and although I run the command `Import-Module Az.DataFactory` I do not see it in the list of installed modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> WARNING: AzureRM.Profile already loaded. Az and AzureRM modules cannot
>   be imported in the same session or used in the same script or runbook.

From last year, `Az` published as a new cross-platform PowerShell module that is completely independent of `AzureRM`. Since `Az` and `AzureRM` use the same dependencies with different versions, it's impossible to run `Az` and `AzureRM` side by side in the same PowerShell session. That's why you receive the first error message.

The first solution is remove all `AzureRM` modules if you don't have script that use `AzureRM`.

But, if you continue want to use `AzureRM` for part of scripts while also writing another scripts with `Az`. You can execute with Azure Powershell task V4.0.

Comment: Setting the task to version 4.0 fixed it for me, thank you!

Comment: I am receiving this message during the run of a pipeline and from what I can see I am not using AzureRM anywhere in my ps.